# Concatenate two DataSet Column in dropdownlist DataTextField while Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dropdownlist that i have to bind from back end. I am using DataSet to bind the Data but need concatenate two column data in datatextfield of Dropdownlist.

Here is my Code.

```
string sqlGetClass = "select * from tbl_studentClass";
SqlCommand cmdGetClass = new SqlCommand(sqlGetClass, conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdGetClass);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
ddlClass.DataSource = ds;
ddlClass.DataTextField = "brachName"+"-"+"classYear";
ddlClass.DataValueField = "pk_classID";
ddlClass.DataBind();
ddlClass.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--", ""));
conn.Close();
```

if I use a single column the dropdownlist is binding fine but when concatenate them it is giving error 
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'brachName-classYear'.
whene binding the Data.

Code running fine is:

```
string sqlGetClass = "select * from tbl_studentClass";
SqlCommand cmdGetClass = new SqlCommand(sqlGetClass, conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdGetClass);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
ddlClass.DataSource = ds;
ddlClass.DataTextField = "brachName";
ddlClass.DataValueField = "pk_classID";
ddlClass.DataBind();
ddlClass.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--", ""));
conn.Close();
```

But i need to concatenate branchName and class Like M.Sc-1st Year.
Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to specify new column in your query, and then use it as a text field:

```
string sqlGetClass = "select [pk_classID], [brachName] + '-' + [classYear] as [classText] from tbl_studentClass";
...
ddlClass.DataTextField = "classText";
```